# Oracle сессия висит даже после закрытия соединения на стороне клиента (connection.Close())

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core

Всем привет.

Я делаю проект на **Asp.Net Core 7**(web API) с бд oracle10g - **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core - v23.2.0-dev**.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Подключаюсь к бд, получаю некоторые данные и закрываю соединение. Однако, когда я проверяю список сессий оракла, сессия висит и имеет статус "inactive". Почему так происходит?

Сам метод взаимодействия с ораклом выглядит следующим образом

```
public async Task Method()
{

    try
    {
        await using OracleConnection connection = new(_connectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        await using OracleCommand command = new("some query", connection);
        await using DbDataReader odr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

        while (await odr.ReadAsync())
        {
            // some code
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // logging exception
    }

    // some code
}
```

Comment: `и закрываю соединение.` - и где ты его закрываешь?

Comment: 'await using OracleConnection connection = new(_connectionString);' насколько мне известно, 'using' вызывает метод 'Dispose', который и закрывает соединение. В любом случае, я уже пытался явно прописывать 'connection.Close()' и это не помогло.

Comment: а при следующем запросе, когда создаётся ещё одна сессия, первая не пропадает?

Comment: При след. запросе сессия обновляется и так же висит. Но более 1 сессии не создается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема, с которой вы сталкиваетесь, связана с тем, что Oracle-сессия может оставаться активной, даже после того, как вы закрыли соединение с базой данных. Это может произойти по нескольким причинам:

1. Пул соединений: По умолчанию Oracle использует пул соединений, чтобы избежать накладных расходов на открытие и закрытие соединения для каждого запроса. Когда вы вызываете await connection.OpenAsync(), соединение добавляется в пул, а при вызове await connection.Close() оно возвращается обратно в пул вместо фактического закрытия. Это позволяет повторно использовать соединение при следующих запросах, что улучшает производительность, но сессия на сервере остается активной.
2. Delay Transaction: Если в процессе выполнения вашего кода есть задержки (например, долгие вычисления, ожидание данных и т.д.), транзакция может оставаться открытой и удерживать сессию, пока транзакция не будет завершена или отменена.
3. Явное использование транзакций: Если вы явно используете транзакции с использованием OracleTransaction, убедитесь, что они завершаются или откатываются после выполнения всех необходимых операций.

Чтобы правильно управлять соединениями и сессиями в ASP.NET Core, рекомендуется использовать инъекцию зависимостей и политику управления соединениями в разделе "ConfigureServices" в классе Startup.

```
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourOracleConnection")));
    // ...
}
```

И далее работайте через этот контекст

```
// UserService.cs
public class UserService
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _dbContext;

    public UserService(YourDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers()
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User>();

        try
        {
            // Выполнение запроса SELECT * FROM users
            users = await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Логирование исключения
        }
        finally
        {
            // Закрытие сессии БД
            _dbContext.Dispose();
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```